# Drawing a graph with chromatic polynomial

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

I have chromatic polynomial,

$$P(k) = k^2   (k-1)^2  (k-2).$$

How can I draw a graph with given equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the vertices be $a,b,c,d,e$, and let the edges be $ab,bc,bd,cd$. Then there are $k$ ways to color vertex $a$, $k-1$ for $b$, $k-1$ for $c$, $k-2$ for $d$, and $k$ for $e$, so you get $k^2(k-1)^2(k-2)$.

Comment: no edge connects to e?

Comment: That's right. That's the only way to get a $k^2$ into a chromatic polynomial, is to have a graph that isn't connected. You could instead have the edges $ab,cd,ce,de$.

Comment: Apology for my ignorant. How come k^2 get into a chromatic polynomial? The graph with is the disjoint union of the triangle and the interval together has chromatic polynomial. => It is what my teacher said. So is this equation mainly two triangles?

Comment: Not sure I understand you. An equation is not any number of triangles, mainly or not. Anyway, the one I gave in my earlier comment is precisely the disjoint union of a triangle and a line segment.

Comment: are you possible actually draw graph with equation? Actually I don't understand your first comment.

Comment: I'm not up to drawing graphs on this website. All you have to do is draw five points, name them $a,b,c,d,e$, and then draw line segments joining the pairs I've indicated as edges.

Comment: Alright. I drew that, I am trying to understand now. Thanks